# Is it possible for some web based applications to have an initial installation step?[Edited]

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I've been only mostly dealt with SPA (Angular, React, Vuejs) when developing web apps, and I've learned that one of the greatest perks of web apps is it doesn't need an initial set up.
Now I've come across this complicated web-based app that installs Windows Services(DB, Server, Process etc.)

Why would a web app want to run its own server as a background Service by installing it on the same machine? How does that make sense?

https://s3.amazonaws.com/gitbook/Server-Admin-2019/ServerAdmin1Pre-InstallationConsiderations/1.02.FMEServerArchitecture.html

Please shed some light, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question seems multiple, and is not clear. For example it seems you make a difference between web aps and web-based app. Perhaps you will find your answers with a search on "n-tier web applications" ?

Comment: @PierreSevrain Hey I'm sorry for the confusion. I tried to search up n-tier web applications but I didn't get much useful information I need. Basically my question boils down to why would this web app wants to install its server as a background service on the same machine? isn't it typical to have a server running 24/7 in a separate computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's much clearer with your edit :)

I see 3 main reasons :

1 - From what I see, the FME server comes with much more than just the web application : workbench, console, custom components (?), ...
The web interface is just a feature amongst others, not the main one.

2 - Server technologies let you easily manipulate local files, data, launch and manage threads, launch and manage tier applications (DB for example), ... and come with a lot of powerful dedicated libraries.

3 - Legacy

... it's surely a mix of the 3

hth